# convert pdf to png and starts with numeral 1

Tags: bash

I tried to convert an pdf to multiple pngs

```
 $ convert -density 150  1.primer.pdf  -quality 100 output.png
```

it work well but the output starts with 0

```
$ ls | grep png | sort -n
output-0.png
output-1.png
output-10.png
output-11.png
output-12.png
```

How could I modify it to start with 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
convert -scene 1 -density 150  1.primer.pdf  -quality 100 output.png
```